# Web Part ApplyChanges not working properly

Tags: web-part, web-part-property, save

I have my Tool Part class to handle the properties of my Web Part. My method to create the properties( CreateChildControls ) is working fine but everytime I run this method it's reading a parameter from a previous postback.

So when I click to apply the changes..

```
public override void ApplyChanges()
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        WebPart1 wp = (WebPart1 )this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
        wp.test = paramet.Text;
    }
```

It's supposed to read the current value of "paramet.Text" right? No..instead of this, it will call CreateChildControls again, this time my variable from a previous postBack doesn't exist, so no values for my "paramet.Text".

Is this the expected behaviour for ApplyChanges? Because this way..my properties will never be saved.

Comment: Why do you call EnsureChildControls? I've followes this example with great success: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-Creating-a-Custom-ToolPart-for-a-Custom-Web-Part.aspx

Comment: just to make sure the child controls are being created. Thanks for the link. I'll have a look at it and I'll say something soon!

Comment: it worked. But I need something different here...Instead of ( this.ddColor.SelectedValue = wp.pColor; ) I'm checking if a variable exists, and if it does, I want to assign instead of wp.pColor. But it doesn't seem to take any effect, with a variable or a regular string..

Comment: @RobertLindgren The like you provide is broken link. can you provide me solution for this.

Comment: @VigneshKumar I think it is jut temp. down, but here is a similar link :https://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/create-custom-web-part-properties-using-custom-tool-parts-with-a-complete-example-code/#more-107

Comment: Make sure your properties are not static or similar. You should post it as a new problem, stating the differences with above post instead of using this comments section.

Comment: @RobertLindgren I have a question here.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97982/asp-net-web-part-applychanges-not-working-properly. can you please help me